# Javascript show all objects that contain a matching string

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I would very much appreciate some help for a solution on a problem which I am really struggling with.  What it is, I have a number of JavaScript objects with various bits of data in them as below:-

```
Object {id: 1, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "the cycle centre,<br />1 new street,<br />penzance,<br />tr18 2lz<br />}
Object {id: 2, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "heliport link road,<br />long rock,<br />bude,<br />tr18 3rg"}
Object {id: 3, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "heliport link road,<br />long rock,<br />bude,<br />tr18 3rg"}
Object {id: 4, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "west end cottage,<br />trescowe,<br />penzance,<br />tr20 9rn"}
Object {id: 5, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "22 joannies watch,<br />saint ives,<br />tr26 2fr"}
```

What i would like to do is to take a user input value and search the objects address for a matching string and if any of the objects contain the string then all details are returned.

So if a user were to type "bude" as their location object 2 and 3 would be returned with their data.  I have the below code which I'm presuming just equals to true so it's going to show every object.  Tried lots of other things such as using match() and indexOf() methods but every object gets returned.

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="form-submit">
// user input:  "bude, united kindgom"

<script>

    $('#submit').on('click tap', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var userInput   = document.getElementById('user-location').value;

        for (var i = 0; i < bikeshops.length; i++) {    
            console.log(bikeshops[i]);

            if($.inArray(userInput, bikeshops[i])){

                // console.log(bikeshops[i].shopaddress);
                // returns everything!
            }           
        }           
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Missing closing `"` at first object `"shopaddress"` property value

Comment: @guest271314 I'm pretty certain that's just a typo and the array of Objects is correctly defined.

Comment: You really don't need jQuery. Using `Array.prototype.filter`: `bikeshops.filter(el => el.shopaddress.includes(userInput))`

Comment: _"What i would like to do is to take a user input value and search the objects address for a matching string and if any of the objects contain the string then all details are returned."_, _"So if a user were to type "bude" as their location object 2 and 3 would be returned with their data."_ Which is requirement?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, possible. A positive for OP to be aware in either instance.

Comment: For the reason why it always seems true is because [`$.inArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns `-1` if it's not found, but `if(-1)` returns `true`. Actually all of these will return `-1`. The reason is you are trying to use `inArray` for an object which isn't valid here so nothing will be "found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` and `String.prototype.indexOf` like:

```
$('#submit').on('click tap', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var userInput   = document.getElementById('user-location').value;

    var result = bikeshops.filter(function(o) {           // for each object o in the array bikeshops
        return o.shopaddress.indexOf(userInput) !== -1;   // filter out only those who have their shopaddress property containing userInput
    });       

    console.log(result); // result will contain only the objects whose shopaddress property contain userInput
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate. At first I couldn't get it to work but realised where i was going wrong.  I was using google auto complete on the input and it was adding extra characters in the string from the user input.  All working now though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```js
$('#submit').on('click tap', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var userInput = $('#user-location').val();
  
  var bikeshops = [
    {id: 1, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "the cycle centre,<br />1 new street,<br />penzance,<br />tr18 2lz<br />"},
    {id: 2, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "heliport link road,<br />long rock,<br />bude,<br />tr18 3rg"},
    {id: 3, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "heliport link road,<br />long rock,<br />bude,<br />tr18 3rg"},
    {id: 4, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "west end cottage,<br />trescowe,<br />penzance,<br />tr20 9rn"},
    {id: 5, shopcounty: "cornwall", shopaddress: "22 joannies watch,<br />saint ives,<br />tr26 2fr"}
   ];

  for (var i = 0; i < bikeshops.length; i++) {    
    if (bikeshops[i].shopaddress.indexOf(userInput) !== -1) {
      console.log(bikeshops[i].shopcounty.toUpperCase() + " - " + bikeshops[i].shopaddress);
    }           
  }           
});
```

```html
<input id="user-location" placeholder="Location...">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="form-submit">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').on('click tap', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let userInput   = document.getElementById('user-location').value;
    //returns array of filtered bikeshops by userInput
    let filteredArray = search(userInput, bikeshops); 

    //Attributes of array we want to print
    let attrs = ['shopcounty','shopaddress'];

    //Generate Html with results, you can change it to <p> 
    generateHtml(filteredArray, attrs, '#myList', 'li', 'ul');


});



function search(term, array){    
  return filtered = array.filter((value)=>{
    return value.includes(term.trim());
  });  
}

function generateHtml(array, attrs, id,tag, openingTag=''){
  let html = openingTag;
  array.forEach((elem)=>{
     let element = `<${tag}>`;
     attrs.forEach((attr)=>{
       element+=` ${elem[attr]}`;
     });
     element+=`</${tag}>`;
     html+=element;
  });
 if(openingTag!='') html+=`</${openingTag}>`; 
 $(id).html(html);
}
```